# llamar al endpoint de Api.Libro desde el Api.gateway usando ocelot 18.0.0 con net 6.0 y docker

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-compose

se que la pregunta que hare es un poco extensa pero quiero ser lo mas claro posible para a ver si me ayudan a solucionar el problema

He creado un proyecto de Api.Gateway con el framework 6.0 y agregado ocelot la version 18.0.0

Ahora este es mi archivo docker-compose.yml
version: '3.4'

services:

tiendaservicios.api.autor:

```
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}tiendaserviciosapiautor

build:

  context: .

  dockerfile: TiendaServicios.Api.Autor/Dockerfile
```

tiendaservicios.api.libro:

```
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}tiendaserviciosapilibro

build:

  context: .

  dockerfile: TiendaServicios.Api.Libro/Dockerfile
```

tiendaservicios.api.carritocompra:

```
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}tiendaserviciosapicarritocompra

build:

  context: .

  dockerfile: TiendaServicios.Api.CarritoCompra/Dockerfile
```

tiendaservicios.api.gateway:

```
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}tiendaserviciosapigateway

build:

  context: .

  dockerfile: TiendaServicios.Api.Gateway/Dockerfile
```

networks:

default:

```
external:

 name: microservicenet
```

y este es mi archivo docker-compose.override.yml

version: '3.4'

services:

tiendaservicios.api.autor:

```
environment:

  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

ports:

  - "6104:80"
```

tiendaservicios.api.libro:

```
environment:

  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80

ports:

  - "6105:80"

volumes:

  - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro

  - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

tiendaservicios.api.carritocompra:

```
environment:

  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80

ports:

  - "6106:80"

  - "443"

volumes:

  - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro

  - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

tiendaservicios.api.gateway:

```
environment:

  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

depends_on:

  - tiendaservicios.api.libro

ports:

  - "6107:80"
```

y Ahora este es mi achivo ocelot.json en el proyecto de TiendaServicios.Api.Gateway
{

"Routes": [

```
{

  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/LibroMaterial",

  "DownstreamScheme": "http",

  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [

    {

      "Host": "tiendaservicios.api.libro",

      "Port": 80

    }

  ],

  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/libro",

  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT" ]

},

{

  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/LibroMaterial/{id}",

  "DownstreamScheme": "http",

  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [

    {

      "Host": "tiendaservicios.api.libro",

      "Port": 80

    }

  ],

  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/libro/{id}",

  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "DELETE" ]

}
```

]

}

Ocelot esta registrado en el archivo program.cs del proyecto de Api.Gaway de la siguiente manera
builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration);

builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("ocelot.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

Mi proyecto de libro se llama: TiendaServicios.Api.Libro( Aca dentro esta creado el archivo dockerFile)

El metodo dentro del controllador LibroMaterialController.cs es el sigiuente

[HttpGet]

public async Task<ActionResult<List>> GetLibros()

{

```
 return await _mediator.Send(new Consulta.Ejecuta());
```

}

Archivo launchSettings.json en el proyecto de TiendaServicios.Api.Libro
{

"profiles": {

```
"TiendaServicios.Api.Libro": {

  "commandName": "Project",

  "launchBrowser": true,

  "launchUrl": "swagger",

  "environmentVariables": {

    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"

  },

  "dotnetRunMessages": true,

  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7130;"

},

"IIS Express": {

  "commandName": "IISExpress",

  "launchBrowser": true,

  "launchUrl": "swagger",

  "environmentVariables": {

    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"

  }

},

"Docker": {

  "commandName": "Docker",

  "launchBrowser": true,

  "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",

  "publishAllPorts": true,

  "useSSL": true

}
```

},

"$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",

"iisSettings": {

```
"windowsAuthentication": false,

"anonymousAuthentication": true,

"iisExpress": {

  //"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:34949"

 

}
```

}

}

La pregunta es: cuando intento ejecutar desde postman el siguiente endpoint
http://localhost:6107/libro
me genera un error 404 Not found, alguien sabe el porque